# In Lyx, what's the difference between view and update pdf?

Tags: lyx

I can't figure out the difference between view (cmd+R) and update (cmd+shift+R) pdf. Searched everywhere, thanks.

Comment: If you are going to cross-post, please link to all of your posts. One of your other posts is located here: http://latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=25258&sid=ed7cc731cdf0869bf85f521ff93eda74 Can you post there an link back to this one please?

Comment: For reasons why, see http://www.latex-community.org/home/latex-community/94-etiquette/454-crossposts. You just wasted the time of Torbjørn T. and StarValkyrie (although perhaps they don't see it that way). I know that sometimes it's not obvious why you should do that so I hope that the above link helps explain how people want to help you, but don't want to duplicate the efforts of others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

View generates the PDF and opens it. If the PDF is already open a new instance of the PDF reader will be created -- this is at least what happens in Windows and (if I remember correctly) Linux. Use this if you haven't got the PDF open already. Update generates the PDF, but it does not open the PDF reader. Use this if the PDF is already open.

[See also the following comment from scottkosty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/208263/in-lyx-whats-the-difference-between-view-and-update-pdf/208266#comment486231_208266):

> Note that in some cases you might not see a difference if you have a PDF open. For example, my PDF viewer (Evince) seems to recognize that I am opening the same file that is already open. It thus does not create a new instance and just updates that file. However, this depends on the behaviour of the individual PDF viewer.

Comment: oh man this is serious over-customization!

Comment: @andy Well, if I were using LyX I wouldn't want a new instance of Sumatra (or whatever PDF viewer I used) to open every time I recompiled the document, so I understand the distinction. Anyways, if you feel this answered your question, you could consider accepting my answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of it, that marks the question as solved. And welcome to TeX.SX by the way!

Comment: @andy note that in some cases you might not see a difference if you have a PDF open. For example, my PDF viewer (Evince) seems to recognize that I am opening the same file that is already open. It thus does not create a new instance and just updates that file. However, this depends on the behavior of the individual PDF viewer.

Comment: @Rodolfo Please look at who wrote the comment. The comment you copied wasn't written by me, so I edited the text to highlight that fact.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Sorry for the mistake. And thanks for the correction.